# Failed to start Git process: Illegal value of environment variable value 'INTELLIJ_SSH_ASKPASS_TOKEN': '

Tags: android, git, github

I've been trying to get rid of this issue for a month now. It keeps returning me this error when I'm trying to commit and push to GitHub. I've tried everything that I can do including reinstalling the Android Studio, logging GitHub account in different ways on Android Studio as well as deleting git files on the project folder.
[error message image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qkHur.png) [notification error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tEZxX.png)